# When a field in my doctrine entity changes, execute this

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm new to symfony2 and on my project I need to:

- update all my users when a field value into another table changes.

I'm thinking of events and listeners of symfony2 (it seems to be the best/cleanest way), what do you guys think? I'm asking because I didn't find a listener into Doctrine already implemented which can raise a flag when a specific filed changes.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: did you get any solution for your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any Doctrine event listeners for a specific field but you could use the Doctrine Lifecycle Events and then check what field is updated in the callback method.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#reference-events-lifecycle-events